# decoding binary raw machine data to readable format using python

Tags: python, raw-data

I have a example.log file which stores some data as seen below.

```
??¯U÷ ¥ @ÿ      @ÿ      @ÿ      @ÿ      @ ô 1sÿ      @
— Ç 1sÿ      @ÿ      @þ Œ 3sÿ      @÷ŸN +sÿ      @&
Q3?Fß•4?ÌñX×EÔó?õ®0+Ý¨å@‰£Â*N¥Fß•4ô<ÙçE:z¹ì¼ý_Æâ        A@¥?øôb        AþŠ@ö        ?@>?‚\$8€=Ç¢`>fd>Ÿï>?Œ„> ýR K e ~
g^a   ÛJ<ÚR@Ë¶?Ðx€„  -??¯øsµ 0‘
Ž +sM 4sûN+ 2s
 oØ %s    © 3s“ ,sçb 0s ý©s s  Zú $súÂ -sk #s'œê 0“(žŒ 4“,œC .“
 ?@>?‚\?¡÷=
```

I want to convert this data to human readable format but do not know how to extract information from this.

Comment: Do you know the format of the data?

Comment: @ Galen. No I do not know. A device is generating this data. At this moment do not know what is called to this type of data.